# A simple proof of the Portmanteau Theorem

Tags: continuity, random-variables, weak-convergence, expected-value

**A premise.** Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables and let $X$ be a random variable. Call 
$$
F_n(x)=\mathbb{P}[X_n\leq x]
$$ 
and 
$$
F(x)=\mathbb{P}[X\leq x].
$$ 
I say that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ and I write
$$
X_n\stackrel{d}{\to} X
$$
if and only if 
$$
F_{n}(x)\to F(x)
$$
for all the $x$ in which $ F(x)$ is continuous.

**My problem.** I am looking for a simple proof of this result (which is part of the more general Portmanteau theorem).

**Theorem.**  *A sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ if and only if 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_n\right)\right]=E[f(X)]
$$
for any bounded continuous function  $f$.*

Any suggestion of textbooks/lectures?

Comment: Call $F_n(x)=\mathbb{P}[X_n\leq x]$ and $F(x)=\mathbb{P}[X\leq x]$. I mean this definition 

$$
X_n\stackrel{d}{\to} X\Leftrightarrow F_{n}(x)\to F(x)
$$

for all the $x$ in which $ F(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Now it should be ok.

Comment: What if you take the function $$h(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 &\mbox{ if $x \leq a$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$ and find $E[h(X_n)]$ and $E[h(X)]$.  Now $h$  is not continuous, can you approximate it by a continuous function?

Comment: Ok, and concerning the other implication?

Comment: There seems to be a proof given here, I don't know if it is the "simplest possible": http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/8_5.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sketch.

You need to show that for each $\epsilon>0$, the inequality $|Ef(X_n)-Ef(X)|<\epsilon$ holds for all $n$ sufficiently large.  You can start out by picking $K$ so that $P(|X|>K)<\epsilon/(2\|f\|).$  There is a finite set of intervals covering the compact set $[-K,K]$ such that $f$ is within $\epsilon/2$ of a constant on each of them. You can make all the above choices so that all the endpoints are points of continuity of $F$.  Now replace $f$ with a piecewise constant function suggested by the above partition of $\mathbb R$ into intervals, upper bounding $|Ef(X_n)-Ef(X)|$ by a quantity that converges to something less than $\epsilon$.